# How to automatically download tar.gz packages of python libraries that already installed on venv at PyCharm

Tags: python

I want to ask that,
There are some packages that I have installed long time ago. I need their tar.gz files.
In java with maven, its possible to download all libraries that installed but is it possible to do this in Python with Pycharm ? If yes how ?
Thanks for answering

Comment: Not sure about the tar.gz, but you might be able to do `pip freeze > requirements.txt` in that activated virtual environment to write a list of all the dependencies.

Comment: Its not the exactly answer but its a good option. But I have tried, i get " TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable"

Comment: I'm not sure how you manage to get a `TypeError`. Can you do `which python` in your env to see which python you're using?

Comment: I have solved with this python3 -m pip freeze > requirements.txt

Comment: Ah, you might have multiple `pip` installation. Indeed using python3 ensures that it uses the right pip version.

Comment: I think I found a way. Let me know if this works. I had not tried it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some quick research and came across the `pip download` option:

See [this PyPI doc page](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_download/)

So I think you can do:

```
python3 -m pip freeze > requirements.txt`
mkdir folder_with_targz
python3 -m pip download -r requirements.txt -d folder_with_targz
```

I attempted this with one of my packages and it retrieves the `.whl` file:

```
pip download academic-ads-bibtex -d testtargz
...
Collecting academic-ads-bibtex
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/51/41/729b93e5e1d52786dfb087daa9e99565a3a8230fd2bffe6202f97a49521b/academic_ads_bibtex-0.2.3-py3-none-any.whl
  Saved ./testtargz/academic_ads_bibtex-0.2.3-py3-none-any.whl
```

Comment: What version of `pip` do you have? I wonder if the URLs have moved.

Comment: Thank you but i get this error requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://pypi.org/simple/..

Comment: Pip version is pip 9.0.1

Comment: Oh, yea you want to update. `pip` is version 21.x.  It worked for me but note that it downloads the `.whl` files.

Comment: I have upgraded it but this time i get this error ERROR: No matching distribution found for ..

Comment: So which package can it not find? You could try to check pip to see if it's there.

Comment: the package is apturl

Comment: Can you provide your list of `pip freeze` in your original question. It seems like that does not exist: https://pypi.org/search/?q=apturl

Comment: That seems to be ubuntu related and not a python package. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptURL